# DoSomething что это?

Tags: c#

Разбираю тест там такой вопрос:
Какие утверждения верны для типа X.

```
using (var x = new X())
{ x.DoSomething(); }
```

и варианты ответов (можно выбрать несколько)

1. тип X может быть структурой, которая реализует IDisposable интерфейс
2. тип X должен реализовать IDisposable интерфейс
3. тип X должен удовлетворять только одному требованию: иметь метод Dispose
4. тип X должен удовлетворять только двум требованиям: быть классом и иметь метод Dispose

А в интернете ничего про этот DoSomething нигде не пишут. Может кто подскажет что это значит?

Comment: Это то же самое, что и foo() или bar() -- попробуйте в переводчике вбить do something. А правильный ответ -- два. Конструкция using используется для disposable.

Comment: так-то вопрос в тесте не про DoSomething, это просто - какой-то там метод.

Comment: @AK: Формально, (1) тоже верно: `X` _может_ быть структурой (но не _должен_).

Comment: @VladD Хм, попробовал -- действительно работает. Не часто пользуюсь структурами в повседневной работе, а такую конструкцию вряд ли бы сделал в продакшн коде.

Comment: @VladD, неа, (1) - не верно, там написано не просто `X` может "быть структурой", а `X` может "быть структурой, которая реализует ...". А ведь реализация `IDisposable()` обязательна. Мы ведь `using` используем не из-за того, что "а вдруг там IDisposable()", а "потому что там IDisposable()"

Comment: @Андрей: Ну а в чём проблема? Утверждение о том, что в данном коде `X` может быть (т. е., код откомпилируется) структурой, реализующей `IDisposable`, верно.

Comment: @VladD, ну как бы если X="Класс, который не реализует IDisposable()". То условие (1) `X может быть ...` не нарушается

Comment: @Андрей по вашей логике это вообще может быт не C#, и не на планете Земля, тогда любой вариант может быть как верен, так и не верен, пока не показаны ответы. Такие варианты Шредингера.

Comment: @tym32167, хм, в том варианте, в котором задача представлена - да, действительно ответы 1 и 2 подходят. Вот если бы было что-то типа "условия при которых код однозначно скомпилируется" - тогда да, только вариант 2. Не внимательно прочитал.

Comment: @Андрей с подобными формулировками, как а п.1, я бы советовал просто отключать мозг и представлять, что вопрос для дет сада. Ведь если так подумать, то, что тип может быть структурой - не означает, что тип может или не может быть классом, а значит, и рассматривать такие случаи смысла нет в простейшей интерпретации варианта ответа.

Comment: @AK зачем вы исправили заголовок? Был нормальный вопрос, пусть и от новичка - а стал вопрос из серии "решите за меня тест" :-(

Comment: @PavelMayorov Заголовок вопроса лучше всего видится в поисковиках (и по ним лучше всего ищется информация), а вопрос был именно про dispose. Честно говоря, не вижу чтобы стало хуже -- но если есть возражения -- откатил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы не смотрите на DoSomething -- вопрос не про это, а про конструкцию using. DoSomething() -- это просто некоторый метод, видно по названию. Могло бы быть и Foo() и Bar().

Ответы 3 и 4 можно отбросить сразу: такой вариант даже не скомпилируется.

```
void Main()
{
    using (var x = new X())
    {
        x.DoSomething();
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class X // : IDisposable
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose");
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

> CS1674 type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible
>   to 'System.IDisposable'

Остаётся выбор между вариантом 1 и 2. В общем-то ничего не запрещает использовать структуру (спасибо, @VladD!), однако необходимым и достаточным условием является условие 2.

Update. Кстати, я тут пишу "ответ 2", но я не прочитал в условии что могут быть несколько вариантов верными. Если так -- тогда нужно и 1 и 2 отметить.